# Purpose of --enable-auto-import Warning

Tags: c++, linker, mingw

I am trying to compile the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello, world!";
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, I get this message:

```
C:\programs>g++ test.cpp
Info: resolving std::cout  by linking to __imp___ZSt4cout (auto-import)
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: warning: a
uto-importing has been activated without --enable-auto-import specified on the c
ommand line.
This should work unless it involves constant data structures referencing symbols
 from auto-imported DLLs.
```

The build succeeds and the executable runs as expected, but this warning still irritates me. I expect a successful build to be completely silent. This message gives the false impression that there's something wrong with my code.

I can silence this error with `g++ -Xlinker --enable-auto-import test.cpp`, but this is undesirable, as it triples the number of characters I need to type to compile a program.

**Questions:**

- Why does this warning appear for the simplest of programs? i don't expect cryptic warnings when I compile Hello World.
- Is it possible to silence this warning without passing the flag to the linker every time? An option in a config file hidden somewhere in `c:\mingw`, perhaps? Or maybe I missed an "automatically enable auto-import" checkbox during installation?

**Possibly Relevant Specs**

- GCC Version 4.5.0
- ld.exe Version 2.20.51.20100613
- Windows XP Service Pack 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some reading and it looks like it might be related to the mingw32 dll not having dllimport attributes defined.

Perhaps there is a patch or you can rebuild mingw32 yourself and add them?

Comment: I did some research myself, and I agree with you. [Here](http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2009-02/msg00341.html) is a discussion from the binutils newsgroup about why the error appears (I think- it's too technical for me). [This](http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils-cvs/2009-06/msg00121.html) appears to be the changelog where they patch it so that `--enable-auto-import` is passed automatically. I'm not sure if I was using a 2-year old linker, but I reinstalled MinGW and the warning is gone.

Answer (score 6):

I used to face same problem as you do with `g++`. I solved this irritating problem just now.  Here is how I come to the solution, step-by-step:

On Windows, you can create an alias of `g++` with all given options which you want to use with `g++`. Say, for example, you want to create an alias `s++` of `g++ -enable-auto-import`, then you run this on `cmd` as:

```
C:\>doskey s++=g++ -enable-auto-import
```

This creates an alias called `s++`. But this alias will not take any command line argument, which means, you cannot write this:

```
C:\>s++ filename.cpp //it is not working
```

To make it work, if you've to tell the alias to accept command line arguments while creating it, so here is how it is done:

```
C:\>doskey s++=g++ -enable-auto-import $*
```

Please note the `$*` at the right, which indicates that now `s++` can take command line argument:

```
C:\>s++ filename.cpp //yayyyy..its working now, without giving any warnings!
```

But you may not prefer to create the alias everytime you open `cmd`. In that case, you can create a shortcut of `cmd`.

For example, I created a shortcut called `Console` and in the `Target` textbox of shortcut window, I wrote this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /K doskey s++=g++ -enable-auto-import $*
```

And since this is too long (horizontally), one screenshot was not able to capture the entire command. I took two screenshots so that you could see yourself how I did it:

- Left part of the command

  [image: Left part of the command]
- Right part of the command

  [image: Right part of the command]

For more information on creating aliases on windows, see this:

- [Creating aliases on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/49170/create-an-alias-in-windows-xp)

Comment: Some build systems don't start process via the shell.