# warning: auto-importing has been activated without --enable-auto-import specified on the command line

Tags: c++, qt, dll

My environment:

- Qt Creator 2.3.1
- Qt 4.7.4 (32 bit)
- Windows 7 Ultimate (64 bit)

While trying to rebuild a project in Qt for Windows, I'm having the following compiler warning:

> warning: auto-importing has been activated without
>   --enable-auto-import specified on the command line. This should work unless it involves constant data structures referencing symbols from
>   auto-imported DLLs.

The project that's emitting this warning includes a DLL file. In spite of the warning, the classes and functions in the DLL are accessible.

What does the warning mean? How to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Purpose of --enable-auto-import Warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742332/purpose-of-enable-auto-import-warning)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a MingW specific warning telling you that several dynamic libraries are being linked in implicitly. That's entirely fine. To fix it, you literally do what the warning tells you and specify the option:

```
g++ -o prog file1.o file2.o --enable-auto-import
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

<sub>(By the way, if you're distributing executables for Windows, you might additionally like to link with `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` to avoid dependence on the compiler's runtime libraries.)</sub>

Comment: *dynamic libraries are being linked in implicitly* - what does this mean?

Comment: @Donotalo: Well, you're not saying `-lkernel32` explicitly, but nonetheless you link with it...

Answer (score 0):

If you use Code::block environment, you have to do this:

The following steps will add the "-Wl,-enable-auto-import" options for a specific CodeBlocks project:

1. Open your project in CodeBlocks.
2. Open the menu "Project" -> "Build Options"
3. Go in tab "Linker Settings"
4. In the text box "Other Link Options",
       type "-Wl,--enable-auto-import"

For adding this option as default to ALL project, follow these steps:

1. go to menu "Settings" -> "Compiler and Debugger..."
2. select your compiler (GNU GCC Compiler)
3. Go in tab "Linker Settings"
4. In the text box "Other Link Options", type "-Wl,--enable-auto-import"