# Suppress g++ warning message "resolving __ZSt4cout" on Windows 7

Tags: c++, g++

Compiling a Hello World (or any other program) on Windows 7. I compile it by using this command:

```
g++ -o cpp_xhello.exe xhello.cpp
```

And I get a warning message:

```
Info: resolving __ZSt4cout by linking to __imp___ZSt4cout (auto-importc:\g95\bin/ld.exe: warning: auto-importing has been activated without --enable-auto-import specified on the command line.
```

This should work unless it involves constant data structures referencing symbols from auto-imported DLLs.)

The program does compile and run. I have the gcc-based g95 Fortran compiler installed at c:\g95. What does the message mean, and how can I suppress it?

I also trying with this:

```
g++ --enable-auto-import xhello.cpp
```

And gives

```
cc1plus.exe: error: unknown pass auto-import specified in -fenable .
```

The g++ version is g++ (GCC) 4.8.0 20130302 (experimental) [trunk revision 196403]

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742332/purpose-of-enable-auto-import-warning).

Comment: I see from a linked thread that compiling with -Xlinker -enable-auto-import suppresses the warning, so the problem is solved.