# Commands 'cin' and 'cout' not working

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw, sublimetext3

I installed MinGW on Windows 8.1 to code in C++ and I am trying to run my codes using Sublime Text 3. So far I am successful, but I am not being able to use `cin` and `cout`. I know I can use `scanf` and `printf`, instead. But I might need to use `cin` and `cout` as well. When I am trying to build a C++ code containing `cin` or `cout`, it gives a compile time error. Let's see at a piece of code which generates such an error:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "cstdio"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << n;
}
```

The error coming up on my machine is: (**Note**:I have WinGHCi installed on my machine to use Haskell)

```
Info: resolving std::cin  by linking to __imp___ZSt3cin (auto-import)
Info: resolving std::cout  by linking to __imp___ZSt4cout (auto-importc:/program files   (x86)/haskell platform/2013.2.0.0/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: warning: auto-importing has been activated without --enable-auto-import specified on the command line.
This should work unless it involves constant data structures referencing symbols from auto-imported DLLs.)

[Finished in 1.4s]
```

Please help me to find what is wrong. I deliberately don't want to use IDEs.

Note that a general suggestion is to use `<iostream>` instead of `"iostream"`. In this regard, using `<iostream>` produces the following error on compiling the same code (with `"iostream"` and `"cstdio"` replaced by `<iostream>` & `<cstdio>`):

```
Info: resolving std::cin  by linking to __imp___ZSt3cin (auto-import)
Info: resolving std::cout  by linking to __imp___ZSt4cout (auto-importc:/program files (x86)/haskell platform/2013.2.0.0/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: warning: auto-importing has been activated without --enable-auto-import specified on the command line.
This should work unless it involves constant data structures referencing symbols from auto-imported DLLs.)

[Finished in 1.8s]
```

Comment: try using <iostream> not "iostream"

Comment: beside you have already declred the use of the namespace std , no need to mention it with cout , just write cout and cin , no need for std::cout

Comment: @ParamjitSingh Are you sure those are errors? It says ‘info’ and ‘warning’ but never ‘error’.

Comment: @Biffen, I can't run this code. I think that makes it an error. If it were a warning, I could atleast run the code. Using command propmt produces an erroe, while compiling, saying:  undefined reference to std::cin.

Comment: @AIL, using 'cin' in place of 'std::cin' gives the same thing.

Comment: Does your mingw install actually reside at `c:/program files (x86)/haskell platform/2013.2.0.0/mingw/`? It could be you have 2 conflicting installs.

Comment: @KillianDS Yes I do have it installed there. What to do now?

Comment: duplicates [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7742332/4074081)? seems to be caused by some older mingw build, try reinstall newer version.

Comment: `cin` and `cout` are not a _commands_, they are a _objects_

Answer (score 1):

These type or errors is often throwned when you are using:

```
 headers with version x
 ----------------------
 lib with version y
```

So, check this.

## update

If you're using compiler with version 4.6.3 but you're using header of 4.6 (for any reason), you got these kind errors.

Useful command:

```
 which g++ #locate where is your compiler (generally /usr/bin/g++)
 g++ --version #get compiler's version
 find / -name iostream | grep c++ #find where're your includes
```

Comment: I can't follow what you said. What should I do to make this work?

Comment: @ParamjitSingh He says that you use header files of a library with for example version 1.1, but you actually link against the library with for example version 1.0.